# two <details> next to each other but not affecting the other when opened

Tags: html, html-tag-details

I'd like to use two details items next to each other using html. However, when I open the first details item, the second item moves to the end of the summary inside the first details item. Is there a way to prevent this?

Here is what I tried:

```html
<div style="display:flex;flex-direction: center;column-gap: 20px">
  <details>
    <summary>Item 1</summary>
    This is a long summary. It's actually even longer.
  </details>
  <details>
    <summary>Item 2</summary>
    This is another long summary. It's actually even longer.
  </details>
</div>
```

How it looks when it's closed.

[image: Closed]

When I open it, the second item moves to the end of the summary text. I'd like to keep it where it stands in closed form.

[image: Open]

Desired Result:

[image: Desire]

Comment: What would the desired result look like if only Item2 is open? Or when both items are open?

Comment: Ah I do not need both Items open at the same time. Item 2 can open under its own item or where Item 1's summary stands. Both work.

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix! You can use various methods, but a straightforward solution is to utilize a grid container. Just place both items inside and apply the appropriate CSS to style and align them within the grid.

```
<style>
  .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    width: 300px; 
    gap: 10px;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <details>
      <summary>Item 1</summary>
      This is a long summary. It's actually even longer.
    </details>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <details>
      <summary>Item 2</summary>
      This is another long summary. It's actually even longer.
    </details>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: It would be great if the summary under Item 1 could grow under Item 2, instead of each wrapping under its own item. Is that possible?

Comment: Edited the question to reflect that. Sorry!